# Gitlab runner - Use ECR registry as registry mirror to reduce calls to dockerhub

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, amazon-ecr

I want to use ECR registry as a registry mirror with gitlab-runner.

How can I pass ECR registry url as registry mirror while register the runner? I have setup the login of ECR from my instance and able to push images to ECR directly so login/auth is not the issue here.

Thanks.

Comment: Set up a separate repo that pulls all the images from docker and pushes to ECR. Update your existing builds & deployments to pull from ECR.

Comment: @SteveE. thats like using our own repo but registry mirror means docker will save images automatically to it if not there or any update happens in it. In your approach I will have to take care of it manually.

Comment: take a loot at here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70464316/mirror-of-gitlab-registry-for-asia/70464539#70464539