# Mirror of gitlab registry for Asia

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, docker-registry, gitlab-pipelines, docker-registry-mirror

Its really hard to push & pull from registry.gitlab.com in pipelines which is not on GCE, there is always an issue like latency or low bandwidth.

Is there any mirror for it or anyway to speedup the docker image push&pull process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit /etc/docker/daemon.json and added registry-mirrors

```
{
   "registry-mirrors": ["https://gitlab.mirrorlist.ir"]
}
```

Now connected to mirror in middle east.

It should be noted that no caching is done and communication is done using NAT.

Kind regards